# Infinite Square Roots : Couldn't match expected type & cannot construct the infinite type

Tags: haskell, ghci

Sorry for what's probably an idiot question - trying to learn Haskell at the moment;

I'm trying to build a basic function that will create an infinite list of square roots on a number, so I can get practice with the take function and how it works.

I wrote the following code;

```
infisqrt x = infisqrt'((x :: Float) [])

-- helper method
infisqrt' x xs = infisqrt'(sqrt(x) (xs ++ [(sqrt(x))]))
```

However, this is returning with two errors when trying to load the library;

```
:l isq

isq.hs:1:24:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[t0] -> a’ with actual type ‘Float’
Relevant bindings include
  infisqrt :: Float -> [a] -> t (bound at isq.hs:1:1)
The function ‘x :: Float’ is applied to one argument,
but its type ‘Float’ has none
In the first argument of ‘infisqrt'’, namely ‘((x :: Float) [])’
In the expression: infisqrt' ((x :: Float) [])

isq.hs:5:33:
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a] -> a
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a] (bound at isq.hs:5:13)
  x :: a (bound at isq.hs:5:11)
  infisqrt' :: a -> [a] -> t (bound at isq.hs:5:1)
In the first argument of ‘sqrt’, namely ‘(x)’
In the first argument of ‘infisqrt'’, namely
  ‘(sqrt (x) (xs ++ [(sqrt (x))]))’
```

Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: A minor side note: `Float` is kind of a special-purpose type, used mostly for algorithms designed specifically around it, or in certain situations where size is more important than precision. Most of the time, the floating-point type you want is `Double`.

Comment: I have flagged this question for closure. There's nothing *wrong* with the question, but it is very unlikely that anyone making this particular mistake in the future will be able to find it—they will end up getting a different error message mentioning different types, in the process of doing something different.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell function invocation doesn't use parentheses. It looks like you're expecting this:

```
infisqrt x = infisqrt'((x :: Float) [])
```

to mean "pass `x` and `[]` as arguments to `inifsqrt`." However, to the compiler, it actually means "pass `[]` as the first argument to `x`, and then pass the result to `infisqrt'`." If you take the extra parentheses out, you should start getting traction:

```
infisqrt x = infisqrt' (x :: Float) []
```

(remember, you've got the same thing going on in `infisqrt'`'s definition)

As a side note, it's typically preferable to put arguments' types in a function type declaration:

```
infisqrt :: Float -> [Float]
infisqrt x = infisqrt' x []
```

Comment: This was actually what I tried to do first - I started adding the paren's, thinking (from an iterative coding point of view) that it would instead make the function more explicit, and give me more "meaningful" errors.

I've gotton the .hs loading by switching to; `infisqrt x = infisqrt' (x :: Float) []

-- helper methods

infisqrt' x xs = infisqrt' (sqrt(x)) (xs ++ [(sqrt(x))])` - but now I appear to get stuck in an infinite loop whenever I attempt to run "take 4 infisqrt 8". Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, yeah. The problem is that you've constructed `infisqrt'` to take the infinite list of results as an argument, but never to return it. Writing it as `infisqrt x = (sqrt x) : (infisqrt (sqrt x))` should work better, although I'm having trouble putting exactly why into words.